# Assert multiple methods being called, only constructor works

Tags: python

I'm trying to test the following function

```
def send_mail(config, message, raw_object):
    smtp_config = config['handlers']['smtp']

    session = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_config['host'], smtp_config['port'])
    if smtp_config['tls']:
        session.starttls()
    session.login(smtp_config['from'], smtp_config['password'])

    for to in smtp_config['to']:
        mail = MIMEMultipart()
        mail['From'] = smtp_config['from']
        mail['To'] = to
        mail['Subject'] = message

        body = yaml.safe_dump(raw_object)

        mail.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

        try:
            session.sendmail(smtp_config['from'], to, mail.as_string())
            logging.info(f"Handler:SMTP {to}: {message}")
        except smtplib.SMTPException as exc:
            logging.error("SMTPException:")
            logging.error(exc)

    session.quit()
```

I have the following test

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch

from kubewatcher.handlers import send_mail


class Test(TestCase):
    @patch("smtplib.SMTP")
    def test_handle__send_mail(self, smtp):
        from_ = "from"
        password = "password"
        host = "host"
        port = 587
        tls = True
        to = ["to"]

        config = {
            "handlers": {
                "smtp": {
                    "from": from_,
                    "password": password,
                    "host": host,
                    "port": port,
                    "tls": tls,
                    "to": to
                }
            }
        }

        message = "message"

        raw_object = {}

        send_mail(config, message, raw_object)

        smtp.assert_called_once_with(host, port)
        smtp.starttls.assert_called_once()
        smtp.login.assert_called_once_with(from_, password)
```

The first assertion, `smtp.assert_called_once_with(host, port)`, works just fine. But the entire test fails with the following error

```
...
AssertionError: Expected 'starttls' to have been called once. Called 0 times.
```

Comment: As an aside, why are you unit testing a third party library? Unless it's validating that a specific bug has been fixed, I never test dependencies. They should have their own test suites to verify their functionality.

Comment: @KirkStrauser I want to ensure the my function is calling specific methods of a third part library based on the config I pass to it. I've updated the question with the function I'm trying to test. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code you're testing:

```py
    session = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_config['host'], smtp_config['port'])
    if smtp_config['tls']:
        session.starttls()
    session.login(smtp_config['from'], smtp_config['password'])
```

This test is working:

```
smtp = patch("smtplib.SMTP")  # Sorta; this is just shorthand
smtp.assert_called_once_with(host, port)
```

The problem is here:

```
smtp.starttls.assert_called_once()
```

But it's actually *correct* for it to fail. Your code isn't calling `smtplib.SMTP.starttls`, but `session.starttls`, which is the thing that `smtplib.SMTP` *returns*.

You can work around that with something like:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock

mock_session = Mock()  # This is the thing we'll be inspecting later
smtp.return_value = mock_session  # `smtplib.SMTP` will return this object

send_mail(config, message, raw_object)

smtp.assert_called_once_with(host, port)
mock_session.starttls.assert_called_once()
mock_session.login.assert_called_once_with(from_, password)
```